# Create pivot table in laravel to display attendance

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am creating an application in laravel for entering attendance. My attendance table name is attendance_tbl . This table contains following columns,
 `id, stud_id, class_id, attn_date, attendance, created_at, updated_at, updated_by`

the attendance column value is 0 for absent and 1 for present.

I want to display consolidated attendance of a week or month as per following requirements. I want rowname as studentname and columnname as Date and cloumnname below attendance.

There is a table named students contains following fields, 
`id, user_id, student_name, class_id, updated_by, updated_at, created_at`

How will I solve this problem??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        foreach (Student::get() as $student) {
            foreach ($student->attendance->orderBy('created_at') as $date) {
                $students[$student->id][] = array('date' => $date->created_at, 'attended' => $date->attendance)
}
        }
```

You would then send the $students value to your view via controller or other methods outside of this scope and iterate over the array.
Ex:

```
<table>
@foreach($students as $student_id => $data)
<tr>
<td>{{$student_id}}</td>
@foreach($data as $d)
<td>{{$d->attended}}</td>
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

If you want to do it for a specific date range or whatever you will need to apply filters either after $student->attendance
Ex: where('created_at' < '12/30/15') or if you want to look at specific students you will need to modify the Student::get()
ex: Student::where('id','=','1')->get();

There are more eloquent ways to do this of course, but I'm not prepared to write a novel.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69880808/laravel-how-would-you-query-this-table-and-group-two-rows-with-the-sameby-their?noredirect=1#comment123526534_69880808  @ajameswolf I could use your help here..

Comment: Whats up @WanjilaAbraham ? What is your problem?