# Laravel: How would you Query this Table and group two rows with the sameby their staff ID

Tags: mysql, laravel

I wish to achieve such a table:
[image: Intended Table]

I currently have this table:
[image: Current Table]

EDIT!!

This is my attendance table in My sql.[image]

This is the attendance table in mysql:
[image: Attendance Table in My Sql]

This is the Staff Table in mySql

[image: Staff Table]

Dashboard Controller

```
 public function index()
    {
           $data = [
           'attendances'=>Attendance::query()
               ->where('type','!=','255')
                ->with('staff')->get()
        ];


        return  view('dashboard.attendance_table',$data);


//        $attendances = Attendance::all(); // or whatever Eloquent query you want that returns a collection
//
//        $grouped = $attendances->groupBy('staff_id');
//
//        dd($grouped);
    }
```

attendance.blade

```
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <div class="card overflow-hidden">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div>
                                    <h6 class="main-content-label mb-1">Attendance Table</h6>

                                </div>
                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="exportexampl" class="table table-bordered border-t0 key-buttons text-nowrap w-100 display " >
                                        <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Staff Name</th>
                                            <th>User ID</th>
                                            <th>Time In/ Time Out</th>
                                            <th>Card No.</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>Time</th>

                                        </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        @foreach($attendances as $attendance)
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $attendance->staff->name }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $attendance->staff->userid }}</td>
                                                {{--                                          <td>{{gettype($attendance->type)}}</td>--}}
                                                <td>{{ ($attendance->type==0) ? 'Time in': 'Time out'}}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $attendance->staff->cardno }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($attendance->timestamp)->toDateString() }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($attendance->timestamp)->format("H:i:s") }}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

How would you group the current attendance table so as to achieve my desired attendance table as shown above.
Note:
Time in is 'type'=0
time out is type =1

Comment: you want to show the latest attendance from each staff or what?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: the latest attendances or today attendances?

Comment: Latest attendance, I intend to get reports every fortnight and every end of the month.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I was eat some foods, look at my answer

Comment: It's okay. We should always eat first. I get an erro/r "Cannot use empty array elements in arrays" , can we link up via team viewer or skype?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$attendances = Staff::leftJoin('attendances', function($join) { 
    $join->on('attendances.staff_id', '=', 'staff.id')
    ->on('attendances.id', '=', DB::raw("(SELECT max(id) from attendances WHERE attendances.staff_id = staff.id)")); 
})
->select(array('staff.*', 'attendances.time_in as time_in', 'attendances.time_out as time_out'))
->get();
```

or if time_in and time_out is placed in different row, try this:

Controller:

$staffs = Staff::all();

in your view .blade.php (inside $staffs foreach):

```
@php
    $time_in = $staff->attendances()->where('type', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first() ? $staff->attendances ()->where('type', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->timestamp : '-';

    $time_out = $staff->attendances()->where('type', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first() ? $staff->attendances()->where('type', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()->timestamp : '-';
@endphp
```

so you can just call $time_in or $time_out in your `<td>{{ $time_in }} - {{ $time_out }}</td>`

Comment: I get an error, Cannot use empty array elements in arrays

Comment: updated. it caused by double comma ','

Comment: Still has an error, missing columns, It will be better if we link up.  It will be in a good position to explain my desired outcomes. Check edit.

Comment: edited, please look at the 2nd syntax

Comment: Sir, It still brings errors, Why because I believe that we are querying the wrong table. I need to join the Time in and out of the Attendance table, not the Staff table. Am only using the staff table to pull the Names of the staff. Because you are really knowledgeable but you have understood the question wrongly.  I also believe that I would make more sense with perhaps a skype call or team viewer. skype is @mamboleta1

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't open my laptop for now, maybe at UTF 05.00, but look at my updated answer, don't forget to create the relation (hasMany) in staff models.

Comment: Still getting errors because there is a mismatch between atttendance table and staff table. Kindly when will you be free? I will hit you up..

Comment: im free now, what is your teamviewer id?

Comment: any chance you are free to help me out, with filtering the attendances according to user type? I need to attach a messaging system to a specific user type using the logic that you shared earlier. I have messaged you on Telegram. Kindly reach out, Thanks

Comment: Hello, still need your assistance on telegram.

Comment: Hello Kind Sir, I could use your assistance on 1. Calculating and displaying the difference in time in and out of each individual user.  2. Displaying each individual user's attendance on a table. I am available on Telegram. Are you available?